# Jenkinsfile agent fails to find source code file

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline running in a Docker container. My pipeline consists of three stages: Build, Test, and Deliver. Each stage makes use of an agent and the Build and Test stages work perfectly. However, for some reason the Deliver stage fails because the `cdrx/pyinstaller-linux:python2` agent that runs the `pyinstaller` command can't find the source code in the mounted volume. I verified the file does exist and is in the correct location. When the job gets to stage 3 "Deliver" it fails to find add2vals.py. Any idea why this is happening, I'm baffled, miffed, jaded. [image: Error Message:]

**Jenkinsfile Pipeline Script**

```
pipeline {
agent none
options {
    skipStagesAfterUnstable()
}
stages {
    stage('Build') {
        agent {
            docker {
                image 'python:2-alpine'
            }
        }
        steps {
            sh 'python -m py_compile sources/add2vals.py sources/calc.py'
            stash(name: 'compiled-results', includes: 'sources/*.py*')
        }
    }
    stage('Test') {
        agent {
            docker {
                image 'qnib/pytest'
            }
        }
        steps {
            sh 'py.test --junit-xml test-reports/results.xml sources/test_calc.py'
        }
        post {
            always {
                junit 'test-reports/results.xml'
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Deliver') { 
        agent any
        environment { 
            VOLUME = '$(pwd)/sources:/src'
            IMAGE = 'cdrx/pyinstaller-linux:python2'
        }
        steps {
            dir(path: env.BUILD_ID) { 
                unstash(name: 'compiled-results') 
                sh "docker run --rm -v ${VOLUME} ${IMAGE} 'pyinstaller -F add2vals.py'"
            }
        }
        post {
            success {
                archiveArtifacts "${env.BUILD_ID}/sources/dist/add2vals" 
                sh "docker run --rm -v ${VOLUME} ${IMAGE} 'rm -rf build dist'"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

**EDIT**
After about two days of almost full time researching and attempts to resolve this issue I've been unable to. As of now I think there is a high likely hood of this being a bug in Docker. The files in the mounted volume just are not visible in the path on the container they are mounted to plain and simple. So be advised, will keep at it and update when I have something useful. If you encounter this I highly suggest just using Dind as oppose to Docker CLI installed on a jenkins container. Note this applies to a Windows 10 host with Docker Desktop installed using Linux containers. Hope this is helpful for the time being.

Comment: Instead of `-F add2vals.py`, try using `-F /src/add2vals.py`

Comment: I'm fairly certain I tried this but I've tried so many things maybe I'm not remembering correctly. Will give it a try now.

Comment: so i did try that already which will just set the path to src/src/add2vals.py which isn't what we want. The volume is already mounted in /src so really it is /src/add2vals.py as is.

Comment: Ok. What does this return? `docker run --rm -v ${VOLUME} --entrypoint pwd ${IMAGE}`

Comment: Did you mean `--entrypoint $(pwd)` by any chance?

Comment: Just `pwd` should work. Did you try running the command i specified?

Comment: That step passed this time! The only issue is `archiveArtifacts` fails now with this `Archiving artifacts
‘28/sources/dist/add2vals’ doesn’t match anything: ‘28’ exists but not ‘28/sources/dist/add2vals’
Error when executing success post condition:
hudson.AbortException: No artifacts found that match the file pattern "28/sources/dist/add2vals". Configuration error?`. Is this because of the added `pwd' possibly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211634/discussion-between-technext-and-after-sunset).